# Getting whole documents from MongoDB and C# by distinct element

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm having a hard time understanding how I should write some MongoDB queries.
Maybe my mind is too accustomed to relational databases.

Anyway, I want to retrieve all documents (whole documents, not a subset of elements) but only one per distinct value of a element.

For example, I have the following 3 documents in a collection:

```
{
  "person": {
     "name": "james",
     "age": "21",
     "city": "London"
  }
},
{
  "person": {
     "name": "edith",
     "age": "18",
     "city": "London"
  }
},
{
  "person": {
     "name": "steve",
     "age": "29",
     "city": "Berlin"
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve whole documents but only with distinct "city" element values. The rest of the data should be there (hence why I cant just $group them) it just doesn't matter which document among the subset that gets returned.

So the desired output should be (in case we always use the first document with the distinct value): (The first document could just aswell be edith, doesn't matter)

```
{
  "person": {
     "name": "james",
     "age": "21",
     "city": "London"
  }
},
{
  "person": {
     "name": "steve",
     "age": "29",
     "city": "Berlin"
  }
}
```

Did that make sense?

(Dummy data, but the problem is a real one)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what your are looking for is:

`GetCollection<Person>("person").DistinctAsync("person.city",filter)`